# How to find vertical and horixontal ground reaction force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

If you were to perform a vertical jump (running and then jumping as high as you could), how would you go about calculating the vertical and horizontal ground force for someone who weighs 60kgs? Assuming the centre of mass is accelerating at 15 m/s^2 at an angle of 68 degrees up and to the right at the instant just prior to takeoff.

Comment: You have the acceleration, just use F = ma. The force you push to accelerate off the ground is equal and opposite to the ground reaction force (hence the term "reaction force")

Comment: "15 m/s^2 at 68 degrees" is a way of expressing a [_vector_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector). Specifically, it is a [_polar coordinate_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) representation. On the other hand, when you say "vertical and horizontal..," you are talking about [_Cartesian coordinates_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). Your first step should be to [convert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) that acceleration vector to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @SeñorO - indeed, but you are have to account for gravity which is opposed by the ground force.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have given the resulting motion and are asked for the forces required in a situation, it is called the **forward dynamics problem**. You essentially apply $F = m a$ along two orthogonal directions.

[image: fig1]

$$ \begin{aligned}
  F_x & = m a_x \\
  F_y - W & = m a_y 
\end{aligned} $$

You use geometry to find the components of acceleration along *x* and *y* directions give the magnitude $a$, and the angle from vertical $\theta$

$$ \begin{aligned}
 a_x &= a \sin \theta \\
 a_y &= a \cos \theta \end{aligned} $$